# EF7 One to One relationships

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I'm currently working on getting a handle on the new EF7 and I am running into an odd behaviour when dealing with one to one relationships.

I have the following models

```
public class Material
{
    [Key]
    [Required]
    [Column(TypeName = "bigint")]
    public long Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(128)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(512)]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Column(TypeName = "money")]
    public decimal CostPerUnit { get; set; }

    public virtual Unit UnitOfMeasure { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Column(TypeName = "bit")]
    public bool IsActive { get; set; } = false;
}


public class Unit
{
    [Key]
    [Column(TypeName = "bigint")]
    public long Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(32)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(64)]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Type { get; set; }
}
```

and I am building the tables as follows:

```
 builder.Entity<Unit>().Key(u => u.Id);
builder.Entity<Unit>().Property(u => u.Name).MaxLength(64).Required();
builder.Entity<Unit>().Property(u => u.Description).Required();
builder.Entity<Unit>().Property(u => u.Type).Required();

builder.Entity<Material>().Key(m => m.Id);
builder.Entity<Material>().Property(m => m.Name).Required();
builder.Entity<Material>().Property(m => m.Description).Required();
builder.Entity<Material>().Property(m => m.CostPerUnit).Required();
builder.Entity<Material>().Property(m => m.IsActive).Required();
```

The problem that I'm having is now that when I try and query for a material with a unit of measure, the unit of measure is always set to null, but when I check the generated tables I can clearly see that the foreign key is actually created.

I've also attempted to force the relationship in the OnModel creating however I'm still unable to retrieve the unit object.

```
builder.Entity<Material>().Reference(m => m.UnitOfMeasure).InverseReference().ForeignKey<Unit>(u =>
```

How should I be adding this reference or is this even supported yet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How are you trying to get the reference? Lazy loading at this point does not work in EF7. You'll have to do eager loading (dbContext.Materials.Include(m => m.UnitOfMeasure)) or the explicit version of that.

Comment: Yes lazy loading was what I was expecting and wasn't sure why it wasn't working. In the interim I'm having to eager load the objects but was really hoping I wouldn't have to. Here's to beta5